# Is there a wildcard for the .Take method in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to create a method using LINQ that would take X ammount of products fron the DB, so I am using the .TAKE method for that.

The thing is, in situations I need to take all the products, so is there a wildcard I can give to .TAKE or some other method that would bring me all the products in the DB?

Also, what happens if I do a .TAKE (50) and there are only 10 products in the DB?
My code looks something like :

```
var ratingsToPick = context.RatingAndProducts
    .ToList()
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.WeightedRating)
    .Take(pAmmount);
```

Comment: Your example is actually taking all of the values from the db regardless of the take.  Move your ToList() till after the take is performed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could separate it to a separate call based on your flag:

```
IEnumerable<RatingAndProducts> ratingsToPick = context.RatingAndProducts
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.WeightedRating);

if (!takeAll)
    ratingsToPick = ratingsToPick.Take(pAmmount);

var results = ratingsToPick.ToList();
```

If you don't include the `Take`, then it will simply take everything.

Note that you may need to type your original query as `IEnumerable<MyType>` as `OrderByDescending` returns an `IOrderedEnumerable` and won't be reassignable from the `Take` call. (or you can simply work around this as appropriate based on your actual code)

Also, as @Rene147 pointed out, you should move your `ToList` to the end otherwise it will retrieve *all* items from the database every time and the `OrderByDescending` and `Take` are then actually operating on a `List<>` of objects in memory *not* performing it as a database query which I assume is unintended.

---

Regarding your second question if you perform a `Take(50)` but only 10 entries are available. That might depend on your database provider, but in *my* experience, they tend to be smart enough to not throw exceptions and will simply give you whatever number of items are available. (I would suggest you perform a quick test to make sure for your specific case)

Comment: I would check pAmmount's value, something like: `if(pAmmount == -1)`. then you can generatate your own wildcard (`-1` in my example).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That might be plausible; I don't know how MaG3Stican determines when the "wildcard" is applicable. And `-1` is a bit of a magic number so I didn't want to assume the condition.

Comment: My linq2SQL is novice level, I only do Linq2Objects, but doesn't the `ToList()` make this a Linq2Objects query and no-longer dependent on the database provider? EDIT: BAH, thats twice now I ask you something and you immediately edit your question clarifying it as I hit "Add Comment".

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yeah, it actually does in this case (I missed that), but I can only assume this was unintended by the asker. I updated my answer to account for this.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Haha, sorry. Guess us great minds think alike! (or perhaps us fools seldom differ?)

Answer (score 2):

Your current solution always takes **all** products from database. Because you are calling `ToList()`. After loading all products from database you are taking first N in memory. In order to conditionally load first N products, you need to build query

```
int? countToTake = 50;
var ratingsToPick = context.RatingAndProducts
                           .OrderByDescending(c => c.WeightedRating);

// conditionally take only first results
if (countToTake.HasValue)
   ratingsToPick = ratingsToPick.Take(countToTake.Value);

var result = ratingsToPick.ToList(); // execute query
```